# AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute '__globals__'

Tags: torch

Encountered when transforming the model using torch.jit.scripts：

File "C:\Users\lyh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\torch_jit_internal.py", line 168, in get_closure
captures.update(fn.**globals**)
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute '**globals**'

model：
class Mymodel(nn.Module):
def **init**(self):
super(Tudui, self).**init**()
self.model = Sequential(
Conv2d(3, 32, 5, padding=2),
MaxPool2d(2),
Conv2d(32, 32, 5, padding=2),
MaxPool2d(2),
Conv2d(32, 64, 5, padding=2),
MaxPool2d(2),
Flatten(),
Linear(1024, 64),
Linear(64, 10)
)
def forward(self,x):
x = self.model(x)
return x
traced_Mymodel = torch.jit.script(Mymodel(torch.Tensor(1, 3, 32, 32)))

How should this problem be solved ？

Comment: Solution: Change torch.jit.script(Mymodel(torch.Tensor(1, 3, 32, 32)) to torch.jit.script(Mymodel)